# Does a piggyback float switch override the default switch?

Tags: switch, sump-pump

What is the real purpose of a "piggyback" float switch?  Obviously it can be used to replace an existing broken switch, but is it also used as a secondary switch? The internet does not have enough information regarding this.  Somebody told me that when using a piggyback float switch the existing switch will be rendered non-functional, ie the new switch is primary - it will activate the motor - and the old switch will do nothing. But how is that even possible - unless the old switch is disconnected or broken?  Note, the existing (default) switch is a double pole switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A piggyback or backup float switch is usually just an additional switch wired parallel to the default switch and has it's float set a little higher than the default switch. If the default switch fails to operate, broken contact, etc., the backup switch will take over when it's float activates it - then the default switch will do nothing but it will still be energized so caution is needed when servicing. If the default switch is functioning properly, the backup switch shouldn't operate unless there's a surge of fluid which exceeds the output of the pump and it's float is operated. In this case, both switches would be closed until the fluid levels dropped below each switch's float level.